# Работа с базой данных на C#, формирование запросов

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

Делаю приложение по работе с базой данных на C#.

Есть реестр в котором отображаются все записи таблицы (реестр).
Так же есть окно для одной записи (окно редактирования).
В окно редактирования я вытягиваю данные с помощью Select запроса с фильтрацией на 1 запись. Вытягиваю результат в компоненты и привязку делаю через DataBinding.

Мне нужно добавить запись в таблицу через окно редактирования, делаю я сейчас следующим образом: прописываю запрос добавления в таблицу примерно следующего вида -

```
string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_Account ('ID', 'Name', 'Code', 'DiscountCardID') VALUES ";
                string Query = string.Format(
                    InsertQuery + "(\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\")",
                    RecordID, edtName.Text, edtCode.Text, (edtDiscountCard.SelectedValue == null ? "" : edtDiscountCard.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

И после чего на новом подключении отсылаю запрос на выполнение. Мне кажется такой подход не правильный. Я знаю, что есть DataAdapter который хранит датасеты (а в них таблицы) и можно через команды задавать команду обновление, добавления и выбора.

Как правильней всего сделать? Плюс есть еще проблемма с внешними ключами когда не выбрано значение из справочника (ComboBox) для этого нужно в запросе (добавления) не передавать на добавление поле. Это приводит к тому что нужно менять сам текст запроса. Это же накладно. Подскажите как сделать правильно :)

Comment: По идее добавляете в проект New Item->Data->Dataset - и там в визуале конфигурите, смотрите по коду что получается, осваиваете технику.

Comment: представьте, что с в после `edtCode.Text` я абсолютно случайно вписал:

    something", ""); DROP TABLE tbl_Account;--